# protobuf fixed size data for a network packet

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to encode a network packet into a protobuf message (bytes) but  I would like to get a message that its size is exactly the same as original packet in the receiver  side.  It looks like protobuf optimizes the size of message. Is that possible?

To make it more clear, how can I make sure what I store in bytes will be remained exactly the same as what I see in the original packet.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the intended scenario of protobuf, and it won't help you do that. There maybe another tool suited for this purpose, but in my experience it is more typical to write packet-focused layers by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I was wrong. I thought that it is gonna change the packet size but it does not. It is just matter of mapping a protobuf message to a well known network packet data structure.

Comment: @AdibRastegarnia and again: that isn't what protobuf is designed for; you can't say "this field is bytes 3-6, big-endian", etc. I think you're looking for a different tool, and that you are mistakenly trying to apply protobuf to a different target scenario

Comment: What I wanna do is to encode a java class with some fields (not all of its fields) into a protobuf message to make it programming language independent and it is possible. One of the fields in that java class is an array of bytes so I defined a variable with type bytes and it works. Is something wrong with this scenario?